# Flex 2 column layout not working on ios 8 safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

This 2 column layout works fine in Chrome and ios9 Safari, however on ios8 safari it turns into a single column layout with all the elements stacked on top of eachother.
https://jsbin.com/tucecivoyu/1/edit?html,css,output

I don't know enough about how the flex standard has changed to come up with a fix for older versions of safari..
I tried using `-webkit-box-oritent`and `-webkit-box-direction` in a few places to see if that would help but couldn't get it to work

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B: Thanks a bunch! Solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using `-webkit-box-flex` and some other prefixes
https://jsbin.com/midewadoba/1/edit?html,css,output